# Owin with MVC 5 - Redirect loop - How to debug?

Tags: debugging, asp.net-mvc-5, owin

I had an MVC 4 application and coverted it into MVC 5 with hopes of using the OWIN middleware.

I succesfully updated to MVC 5 and implemented OWIN this article http://www.khalidabuhakmeh.com/asp-net-mvc-5-authentication-breakdown-part-deux.

When I access the application homepage I get redirected to the specified login URL, however then it starts redirecting to the login URL again until browser ends the attempt with a redirect loop error.

It seems like my login controller is regarded as if it needed authenticating even though there's no Authorize attribute set. I tried adding AllowAnonymous attribute but there was no change.

I have no idea how to debug what OWIN is doing, I set up several breakpoints throughout the app and it seems like my code is never accessed at any point so the redirects must happen at the middleware level.

Here's my OWIN config in the startup class:

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
                   LoginPath = new PathString("/login"),
                   LogoutPath = new PathString("/sign-out"),
                   SlidingExpiration = true,
                   ExpireTimeSpan = new TimeSpan(0,30,0),
                   AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Active
            });
```

When I choose passive mode I just get an unauthorized error page, no redirects happen.

Any idea how to proceed in my scenario? Is there a way to debug what is happening?

Thanks for your help,

Vilem

Comment: Same probleme here. Hope someone will find this, favorited.

Comment: @Crank Please see my reply for a "sort of a" solution. And greetings, fellow czech developer. :) Vypadá to že řešíme podobné problémy, nechceš se spojit? Kdyžtak jsem na LinkedIn.

Comment: Platí stále nabídka? Já jen, že jsem si všiml až dnes, po dvou letech :-D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT:
Upon later investigation the issue was caused by "SecuritySwitch" plugin. I had to remove it entirely, seems like it simply doesn't work with MVC5 + Owin.

ORIGINAL:
I solved this by installing Visual Studio 2013 trial (I use 2012 normally) and creating a new MVC5 project with individual user accounts authentication template set.

Then I started migrating my code piece by piece from the problematic project to this one hoping to find the breaking point. I did not find any, my code worked as I wanted when I migrated it fully.

Obviously this is not a real solution but it got the job done. Simply building the project from scratch saved hours/days of headaches.

Answer (score 3):

I too was following the article you mentioned but found myself in a redirect loop despite my code matching the article code.

I fixed my redirect after a hint here http://forums.asp.net/t/1960987.aspx?After+converting+MVC+4+project+to+MVC+5+I+am+getting+an+error+this+website+has+redirect+loop+ which advised that IIS Express holds site specific authentication settings in a local config file.

> If you are playing with different authentication settings, IIS Express
>   stored additional authentication settings in it's configuration file.
>   Something like:

```
<location path="WebApplication1">
    <system.webServer>
        <security>
            <authentication>
                <windowsAuthentication enabled="true" />
                <anonymousAuthentication enabled="false" />
            </authentication>
        </security>
    </system.webServer>
</location>
```

> Configurations are in user's Documents folder
>
> Documents\IISExpress\config\
>
> and you should look for
>
> applicationhost.config
>
> Then just delete 'location' xml node

Adam

Answer (score 2):

I became crazy for 1 day and in the end I created a new project and reported a view at a time, then a controller at a time until the error occurred.

I found that in the Layout page, there were some Action which was needed authentication and this was causing the redirect.

```
    For example:
<a href="@Html.Action("Create","ads")" class="btn btn-primary navbar-btn btn-sm">
```

I have changed to:

```
<a href="/Create/ads" class="btn btn-primary navbar-btn btn-sm">
```

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! This saved me what most likely would have been hours of debugging!